Integral against radially symmetric function: can I use some sort of "evenness"?
Suppose $\Omega = [-L,L]^{d} \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and let $f$ be a real-valued and radially symmetric function on $\Omega$. Suppose I have $d$ functions $g_{1},...,g_{d}: [-L,L] \to \mathbb{R}$ and we set $g(x) = g(x_{1},...,x_{d}) = g_{1}(x_{1})\cdots g_{d}(x_{d})$.
Suppose an odd number of functions $g_{i}$ are odd $g_{i}(-x) = -g_{i}(x)$, and the remaining are even. Then $g$ is odd. If I want to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{\Omega}f(x)g(x)dx,$$
does this imply that the integral is zero? I am a bit confused because I am in $d$-dimensional spaces, but $g(x)$ is odd and $f(x)$ is radially symmetric, so intuitively $f(-x) = f(x)$, since it depends only on $|x|$, right? And then $\Omega$ is a symmetric domain, so it makes sense that the integral is zero. However, I am using some concepts from one-dimensional spaces and I am not sure if my conclusion holds.

Assume first that $f$ is measurable radially simple functions, i.e., there exist measurable set $A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_{2n}\in\mathcal B(\Omega)$ where $A_{i}=-A_{n+i} $ for $i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} a_k{\bf 1}_{A_k}(x),\quad a_{i}=a_{n+i} \,\,{\rm for}\,\, i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}.
$$
Then we can easily find that $\int_{\Omega}f(x)g(x)dx=0$. For radially symmetric function $f$, we can approach it by radially simple functions and get the conclusion.
